# What folder structures are changed when doing a version upgrade

Tags: upgrade, filesystem

When upgrading from a LiveCD / LiveDVD / LiveUSB from any older Ubuntu version to a newer one, what folders get deleted/modified/kept intact. For example, I know that `/home` stays along with everything in it (Except configuration files that get updated). But for example what happens to the following folder in an upgrade:

`/var`

`/etc`

`/usr`

and others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For modified configuration files in /etc, the installer will ask whether to keep to original or override it.

As for the other folders, an upgrade basically consists of upgrading a lot of packages. File contained by packages are upgraded or removed if they are no longer required.

Files that are created by you and not contained by a package are generally untouched. For example, a common place to store apache 'website' files is in /var/www. These are not removed in an upgrade as far as I know.

Nevertheless, I would recommend to backup important files before an upgrade